# Pyinstaller, adding subfolder path to sys.path

Tags: python, pyinstaller

How to make pyinstaller add path to a subfolder with packages inside the bundle? 
I'm creating One Folder bundle using spec file. I want to keep some packages in a separate subfolder inside the bundle but the program doesn't see those packages.(it can load those packages only when I move them to the main folder). So I have add subfolder path to sys.path to make it work.
After compilation when I run exe file, `print(sys.path)` shows two paths: `['C:\dist\MyProgramFolder\base_library.zip', 'C:\dist\MyProgramFolder']`
I want it to show extra path to my subfolder (so I can load packages from there) like this: `['C:\dist\MyProgramFolder\base_library.zip', 'C:\dist\MyProgramFolder', 'C:\dist\MyProgramFolder\Subfolder']`
Of course I can add  extra path in the beginning of Python script: `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.path[0]),'Subfolder')`.

But is there any way to make pyinstaller add this path automatically during compilation? Or is there another way to load packages from subfolder ?

Comment: another way of thinking is how you have referred to the folders in your python program.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily using [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html).

Sample project folder structure is below.

```
.my_project
├── __init__.py
├── _module_a
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── some_func.py
├── utils.py
└── setup.py
```

**utils.py**

```
def func_util():
    print("func_util called..")
```

**some_func.py**

```
from my_project.utils import func_util


if __name__ == "__main__":
    func_util()
```

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='my_project', version='1.0', packages=find_packages())
```

- cd my_project (/path-to-root-your-project)
- python -m venv venv (create virtual environment)
- /venv/Scripts/activate (activate your venv for windows)
- pip install -e . (. stands for root folder our project)

### running some_func.py

```
(venv) PS C:\path_to_your_project_folder> python .\module_a\some_func.py
func_util called..
```

Comment: I will have a look at setuptools but I don't know how it helps. I was asking about adding extra path to a folder with packages (inside the bundle) when compliling my app with pyinstaller.